# simple mongo query to aggregate collections stats

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out if there's a nice way to get a result set from mongo that would give me an over view of all collections in a db.

I see the stats method per collection, which includes a storageSize field that I'm interested in.   I'd like to get collections and their storageSizes in a single query with out just doing

```
db.col1.stats();
db.col2.stats();
db.col3.stats();
```

In MySQL the equivalant query of what I'm trying to do could look like

```
select table_schema, table_name, sum(data_length+index_length) from       
information_schema.tables group by 1,2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = db.getCollectionNames();
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var comm = db.runCommand({ collStats: arr[i] , scale : 1024 });
    print (arr[i] + "\t" + comm.storageSize);
    // or if you prefer json:  
    // printjson({"coll" : arr[i], "storage" : comm.storageSize})
}
```

Note the scale (KB)